# Problems with RS232 cable and the communication

Tags: usb, python

Let me start out by saying that I hope this is the right place to ask.

My problem is not purely defined yet and I am hoping you can help me shed some light on what is going wrong.

So, the deal is that for my electronics exam project my group and I have made an ECG mainly to monitor the heart rate. We would then like to take the data we get and send it to the computer and from there draw a graph of the actual ECG. The electronics board and that are working perfectly. We take our heart rate frequency and put it through and AD-converter (written in Assembler). After that we take the output signal through an optocoupler and from there to our RS232 cable and into the computer.

I believe that I have correctly installed the VCP drivers from FTDI. When I say I believe it is because I followed the installation instructions and all went well however when I try the example I get an error:

```
casper@casper-ThinkPad-L530:~/Downloads/release/examples$ make -B
for n in BitMode EEPROM/erase EEPROM/read EEPROM/write EEPROM/user/read EEPROM/user/size EEPROM/user/write Events LargeRead MultiThread SetVIDPID Simple Timeouts ; do make -C $n || exit 1; done
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/casper/Downloads/release/examples/BitMode'
gcc main.c -o bitmode -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib  
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `InitCheckDevice':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to `dlopen'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `dlopen'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x378): undefined reference to `dlsym'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `my_init':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x44c): undefined reference to `dlclose'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x488): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `my_fini':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x4cd): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `DeviceMatch':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x537): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `FTCommonOpen':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x229c): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x22dd): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x232b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(ftd2xx.o): In function `FT_Close':
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x2630): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x2670): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
ftd2xx.c:(.text+0x26dd): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(io.o): In function `libusb_try_lock_events':
io.c:(.text+0x8d5): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(linux_usbfs.o): In function `find_monotonic_clock':
linux_usbfs.c:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a(linux_usbfs.o): In function `op_clock_gettime':
linux_usbfs.c:(.text+0x323b): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
linux_usbfs.c:(.text+0x3250): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bitmode] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/casper/Downloads/release/examples/BitMode'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 1
```

This is my first issue, I am not sure how to fully check out whether or not the driver is actually working. I can see the cable perfectly when executing:

```
casper@casper-ThinkPad-L530:~/Downloads/release/examples$ ls -h /dev/*tty*
```

I can find:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

But something tells me that this is NOT the virtual COM port is should be in order for the RS232 protocol to work.

Which leads to my second problem. This is probably only a problem because of the above but nonetheless:

I am just starting to use PySerial to work with the cable but I cant seem to get the grasp of how to do this. When executing the following:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=10)

x = ser.read()

print x

ser.close()
```

The Shell just hangs, as if no bytes are received, after the 10 second timeout, it closes. I know for a fact that I am sending a signal through the cable as I am able to see the result on the oscilloscope.

If you need any more information or pictures of anything please do not hesitate to ask, I will gladly provide you with what you need.

Looking forward to hearing from you, Best regards!

EDIT:

While digging through more of the PySerial documentation I tried the following:

```
import serial
import io

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=1)
ser.baudrate = 19200

print ser

ser.close()
```

And get the result:

```
Serial<id=0x98dad6c, open=True>(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=19200, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

I also tried:

```
casper@casper-ThinkPad-L530:~$ python -m serial.tools.list_ports regexp
```

And get:

```
Filtered list with regexp: 'regexp'
no ports found
```

Hope this helps anything?

Comment: I should add that I have cross-posted this on stackoverflow as well as I really need help here, we need to deliver this project on Monday. Sorry if it is inconvenient and if it is against the rules I will undo it.